# Como chamar Finish() de uma classe separada?

Tags: java, android, classes, método

Tenho uma aplicação onde quando o usuário clica em "Voltar" na `MainActivity` ele exibe um `AlertDialog`no método `onBackPressed()` perguntando se realmente quer sair do aplicativo. Porém criei uma nova classe `Gerenciar` para gerenciar, e colocar todos os métodos lá. O problema é que não estou conseguindo inserir o `Finish()` nesta classe e chamar na `MainActivity`. Como proceder?

#### 1 - Código na `MainActivity` funcionando:

```
    public void onBackPressed() {

    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Atenção!");
    builder.setMessage("Deseja realmente fechar o app?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {}
    });
    alerta = builder.create();
    alerta.show();
}
```

#### 2 - Código na classe `Gerenciar` não funcionado:

```
    public void Alertar(){
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Atenção!");
    builder.setMessage("Deseja realmente fechar o app?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            activity.finish();             //Finish() não aceita, e com o `activity` aceita, mas quebra a aplicação quando executa
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {}
    });
    alerta = builder.create();
    alerta.show();
}
```

#### E chamo este método na `MainActivity`:

```
    public void onBackPressed() {

    final Gerenciar negGer = new Gerenciar(this);
    negGer.Alertar();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa chamar o método `finish()` desta forma abaixo:

```
((Activity) context).finish();
```

Um exemplo básico:

```
public class classA{

    Context context;

    public classA(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    void exemploMetodo(){
        ((Activity)context).finish();
    }
}
```

Adaptando ao seu código:

```
public void Alertar() {
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Atenção!");
    builder.setMessage("Deseja realmente fechar o app?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            ((Activity) context).finish();

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {}
    });
    alerta = builder.create();
    alerta.show();
}
```

Comment: Na classe `Gerenciar` ou na `MainActivity`?

Comment: Na classe que você chama o Diálogo.

Comment: @JonasVieira alterei para context, porque vi que você está chamando o context no seu AlertDialog. Só precisa isso e chablauuuu...